# Adding enum to combobox

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hi may i know how to get the enum value below to bind into the combobox?
I wrote the below code which works well but wonder is this the best way.

```
public enum CourseStudentStatus
{
  Active = 1,
  Completed = 2,
  TempStopped = 3,
  Stopped = 4,
}

//Bind Course Status
Dictionary<string, int> list = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (int enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus)))
  list.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(CourseStudentStatus), enumValue), enumValue);
var column = ((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv.Columns["studentCourseStatus"]);
column.DataPropertyName = "StudentStatus";              
column.DisplayMember = "Key";
column.ValueMember = "Value";
column.DataSource= list.ToList();
```

**----------------- UPDATE -------------------**
Hi i have changed my code to this according to Sanjeevakumar Hiremat and it works perfectly.

`cbStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));`

However, when i want to a Get() and want to bind the value back to the cbStatus, it cast error  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
`cbStatus.SelectedValue = Course.Status;`.

The cbStatus.Datasource is not empty and it has value after bound to `cbStatus.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));`

please advice.

Comment: i am thinking is it possible to reduce this junk of code? or could this be converted to a function?

Comment: you could put your conversion to a dictionary into an extension method for System.Enum, which would make your code more readable and general, but I don't think there is a way to bind to an enum without doing all the GetValues and GetName stuff.

Answer (score 18):

Following should be the simplest way to bind it.

```
column.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CourseStudentStatus));
```

To get the selected value you need to cast it to the enum type.

```
CourseStudentStatus selectedValue = (CourseStudentStatus)column.SelectedValue
```

[Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) returns an array of the enumType values which can then be bound to any control.

I've tested this on a standalone combobox, not in a combobox column in DataGridView, YMMV.

Comment: Should be fine in a DataGridView - the same properties are exposed for binding.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: how do i bind back to combobox after Get().   cbRole.SelectedValue = user.RoleId;//after Get()

Comment: what is the displaymember and valuemember i should set ?

Comment: i got error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} at cbRole.SelectedValue = user.RoleId;

Comment: I think cbRole or user or user.RoleId one of these is null.

Comment: ya i agree, but why would it be null since i have added this cbRole.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RoleType)); RoleType is an enum

Comment: I have tested the cbRole, it is not null. It has value. But when it go through this `cbRole.SelectedValue = user.RoleId;`, then it cast with `object reference not set to an object`. If i do this `cbRole.SelectedText = Enum.GetName(typeof(Enums.RoleTypes), user.RoleId);` then it has value but it append the text to the combobox.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: Any idea?

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath: hi i still failed to bind the value to the cb. could you help>

Comment: on standalone combobox that works for me great, thx! belinq try .SelectedItem=user.RoleID instead .SelectedValue or .SelectedText

Comment: @belinq you may want to accept the answer that best suits your question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a best way.  I used to do something similar with a `GenericListItem<T>` class where T is the backing value, in your case, an enum.

This class exposed `Display` string and `Value` T properties to bind to.  I think I was also overriding `ToString` because it is the default if you don't specify the `DisplayMember`.  I went further and made a constructor taking just `Value` and defaulting `Display` to `Value.ToString`, which in the case of enums works I think.

I'd then make a `List<GenericListItem<T>>`, feed that into the `DataSource` of the column and set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties accordingly in code.  This list is the alternative to the dictionary used in your example.

But I'm not saying it's a better solution :-) however it means you can remove code, say enum iteration, into this class or specialise the class for handling certain data types better, all with the end goal of being inserted into a list and bound to a control.

Comment: Can you tell what you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember to?

Comment: @kirsteng The `Display` property was the `DisplayMember` and the `Value` property was the `ValueMember`. My class was generic so you also had to provide a way to get the string representation of whatever the value was. You could do that using a `Func<T, string>` or something.